# How to vectorize an image while keeping it crisp

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I have been given the task to take graphs and vector them to make them be able to scale up and down. Every time I live trace it, it comes out blotchy and I cant get it to remain someone crisp. I cam easily make the number increments out side of the graph easily but the information inside is very complicated to just try and recreate using the pen tool or anything

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems as though you know the answer.. no tracing, use the pen tool and draw.. it just won't be easy.

Comment: Do you have the original data? I mean not just a image?

Comment: To make the Trinity complete, I say: There's no problem (tried and saw) with the tracing if you allow some error, say max. 1 pixel displacement when compared to your image and the visual appearance is = no error, when zoomed to fit the screen.  Do you accept it? Only filter out the JPG artefacts before tracing. NOTE: Your curves are about 1 pixel wide black and white without any smoothing., like staircases. Graphic software tracing cannot find a smooth zero width curve which can be considered to be the right form of the original. Exactly traced curve is a replica of your image

Comment: It has no sense at all tracing that image! That image, in any case, should be re-generated with the original data.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I think you have been sent on a fools errand. Auto tracing that image will never look good.

As for scaling it, there is no problem.  The image is a bitmap with solid pixels. This could easily be rescaled in Photoshop using *Nearest Neighbour (preserve hard edges)* as the interpolation method.

For example, here's an enlargement of just one small section. Click on it to see it full size.

[image]